# WebDriverException: unknown error when running Selenium on Google App Engine using ChromeDriver and headless option

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-app-engine

I have deployed my application on Google App Engine. I am trying to run Selenium for scraping.
I am using this code:

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1536x754")
    
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

and i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/srv/threads.py", line 28, in rss_scrape_delay
        run_rss_feed(case_study, rss_url, email, password, pages)
      File "/srv/bot_functionalities/scraping_bot.py", line 39, in run_rss_feed
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
        super().__init__(
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
        super().__init__(
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
        self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

I have even tried giving directly `chromedriver.exe` path but still not working.

I have tried adding the chrome.exe path as well from local, then I did `gcloud app deploy`.
It is working fine on my local Windows, but not on gcp app engine

Comment: What is your Selenium version?

Comment: If you're running this on Google App Engine Standard, then it won't work because Selenium doesn't work on GAE Standard (GAE standard only allows installation via Pip and Pip only installs packages from PyPI & Chrome and Web driver aren't available on PyPI; your best bet is to either try GAE Flex or Cloud Run)

Comment: @doneforaiur version 114.

Comment: @NoCommandLine thanks for the response. How can I change it to Flex? Also how can I install Chrome and Web driver after that?. Because right now I am just doing every changes in local and just do `gcloud app deploy`

Comment: @NoCommandLine and for some reason I started getting this error now.
`File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`. Please let me know how can I resolve these issues and make my app work on app engine. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about Flex but we have a [blog article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-use-headless-firefox-on-cloud-run/) on how to do it on Cloud Run. At a high level, Cloud Run is cheaper than GAE Flex because Cloud Run can go down to 0 instances (like GAE Standard) when you don't have traffic but GAE Flex requires that at least 1 instance is always up

Comment: @NoCommandLine Thanks for the response and info. But the issue is I have a flask application on GAE. The app has three endpoints functions. Each of them runs a thread inshort they run independently. One of them starts a selenium bot. So do you think it's possible or is there any way that I can trigger the selenium bot (running on Cloud Run) from GAE front end somehow. Means I can run both Cloud Run and GAE, and from GAE ui button it starts selenium operation?. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can invoke a Cloud Run endpoint from a GAE App. You deploy a Cloud Run App which gives you a url. Then you invoke the url from your GAE App using something like urllib.Request. Best practice is that you should secure your Cloud Run so that it can't be invoked by just typing the url in a browser (this will prevent it from being accessed by the public), then your GAE program calls the url, it will pass the right token which will grant access. See this [blog article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-secure-your-cloud-run-service/) from us on how to secure your Cloud Run endpoint